# MySQL: You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try to run the query below, I get "You can't specify target table 'list' for update in FROM clause"

I know there are actually quite a few other replies about similar issues, but my grasp on SQL isn't so strong as to be able to reconstruct it from someone elses solution.

```
update list
set li = '6'
where li = '5
   and dn in ( SELECT dn FROM list GROUP BY dn HAVING COUNT(*) < 2000 )
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO if it was a homework, atleast the OP did try to post what he has tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting this error?

> You can't specify target table 'list' for update in FROM clause

It's because you cannot update the table directly if you are using it on another subselect statement. One alternative of this is to join the table with itself.

```
UPDATE  list a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  dn 
            FROM    list 
            GROUP   BY dn 
            HAVING  COUNT(*) < 2000 
        ) b ON a.dn = b.dn
SET     a.li = '6'
WHERE   a.li = '5
```

Comment: Please; stop adding unnecessary tags to questions. This just makes it look like you're doing it to get the badges. Myself and others will continue to remove them and roll them back if need be. [Reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176318/what-is-considered-incorrect-tagging).