# MySQL: You can't specify target table 'list' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to run the following query:

```
update list
set li = '6'
where li = '5'
and dn in ( SELECT dn FROM list GROUP BY dn HAVING COUNT(*) < 2000 )
```

This query results in the error mentioned above:

```
You can't specify target table 'list' for update in FROM clause
```

So I got advice from someone who advised me to run the following:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE  list a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  dn 
        FROM    list 
        GROUP   BY dn 
        HAVING  COUNT(*) < 2000 
    ) b ON a.dn = b.dn
SET     a.li = '6'
WHERE   a.li = '5';
```

This code runs - problem is it never finishes.  I'm not sure if it's a problem with the statement itself or if it's because of the 4million records it's trying to work itself through, but I left it going last night when I went to bed and it hadn't finished this morning.  Also, just an afterthought:  I did try to roll this into a transaction in case things went fugly so threw in a 'START TRANSACTION;' at the start of this.

I get the impression this is a fairly common question on here - but I'm not SQL savvy enough to take someone elses query and adjust it to fit my own needs, unfortunately. :p

Can anyone guide me to a solution that will allow me to update these records?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Ummm.. just asking.. Are you sure about `WHERE   a.li = '5`, I mean it should be like `WHERE   a.li = '5'`

Comment: Tweaked.  The ending ' was in the actual query.

Comment: You might need add `COMMIT` after the SQL statement. Not sure if MySQL does automatic commits.

Comment: Is there at least an INDEX on the `dn` column? GROUPing BY that column is definitely going to be slow otherwise... And is the `li` column really of type VARCHAR ? String comparisons are slow, if you can replace this by an INTEGER column you could gain some performance.

Comment: Well, the point was so that I could have the ability to rollback in case things went awry.  I'd need to see the query finish before I could throw in a commit.  I don't have transactions enabled by default, it's something I have to begin manually.

Comment: @MiklosAubert - No index on dn column.  li column is actually int, not varchar.  You're suggesting I remove the surrounding ticks from the references to li?

Comment: Duplicate of [MySQL: You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160517/mysql-you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work, so, continuing from my comment above, here's an answer :

Yes, remove the quotes around '6' and '5', you don't want MySQL to cast the `li` column to a string on every comparison... and do create an index.

```
CREATE idx_dn_li ON list(dn, li);

UPDATE  list a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  dn 
        FROM    list 
        GROUP   BY dn 
        HAVING  COUNT(*) < 2000 
    ) b ON a.dn = b.dn
SET     a.li = 6
WHERE   a.li = 5;
```

The index will make your `GROUP BY` faster, and I think having the `li` column in there can also help (as I see it, in the case where no records are affected, your query should only ever read the index, but don't take my word for it ;) )

Answer (score 0):

This error is generated when we are trying to update a table and we are also having the same table in another query to update a column.

We can't select from a table you're updating at the same time. However, we can do multi-table updates like

```
UPDATE tbl AS a
  INNER JOIN tbl AS b ON ....
  SET a.col = b.col
```

Or try the simplified version of your query

```
update list l1, ( SELECT dn FROM list GROUP BY dn HAVING COUNT(*) < 2000 ) AS l2
set li = '6'
where li = '5'
and dn = l2.dn
```

Hope it helps..
Here is the reference for you... http://7php.com/mysql-update-select-statement-1093/

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
update list
set li = '6'
where li = '5'
and dn in ( SELECT a.dn 
            FROM (SELECT * FROM list) a 
            GROUP BY a.dn 
            HAVING COUNT(*) < 2000 )
```

This query probably will be much more faster:

```
UPDATE list t
SET t.li = '6'
WHERE t.li = '5'
AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM (SELECT * FROM tik) a 
     WHERE a.dn = t.dn) < 2000
```